# Smeagol's past story

Tags: plot-explanation, the-lord-of-the-rings

I was wondering which part this scene in LOTR where Smeagols past was revealed.

I remember it was very beginning of *The Two Towers* but I haven't seen it while I was watching it today after so many years.

I remember the scene which I watched extended DVD version. Is this part of extra scenes which were screened in theaters or not available in the regular movie?

Or am I wrong because my friend claims it was revealed in the Hobbit series of movies?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's in **The Return of the King** as the video title suggests. And as far as I remember it's in the original theatrical cut, just at a different position and a bit shorter.

The first two movies only use tiny bits from it, for example a hand grabbing the ring underwater. It's first implied it's Smeagol's hand, which isn't true as revealed later.

Gandalf also mentions it during the events of the Hobbit, but it's just one or two scenes talking to Bilbo without new visual footage.